# XCode: Storyboard adds extra spaces between elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have this ViewController in my app's Storyboard:

[image]

There's an category image and then under it there's the category title.

When i test the app, the storyboard adds extra spaces at the top and bottom of the category title like this:

[image]

How can i remove the extra space!?

**EDIT**

This is the structure:
[image]

Comment: i'm not sure why this happens as you don't describe the whole story, but i'm sure if you make the cells programmatically you will have 100% control over this excess space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been because of the constraints used and the difference in screen size. The height of the view (containing the fruits image and fruit) has increased. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Okay, so how can i resolve this ? note that i need the app to work on all ios screen sizes

Comment: Will keep it simple. First clear all constraints. For the view with the fruits image and fruit label set height contraint alongwith top, left and right constraints. And for the table view set the top,left,bottom,and right constraints. For the and fruit image fruit label, set top width and height contraint and tick horizontally in view. That's it. You are good to go.

Comment: Let me know if it worked. Else i will walk you through the solution

Answer (score 0):

Select your image then hold control+RMB and lead mouse to label. Release mouse button and choose "Vertical spacing" in menu that apperas.